# Angular 2: How would you display an array as a series of Key/Value pairs?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm pulling in JSON data from an external data source and part of the payload is an array that needs to be displayed as a series of key/value pairs.

I realize one way would be to transform the array into an interface/object via Typescript but in my case the data needs to be transformed declaratively in the Angular template's html markup.

So, given some data in the form of: 
`heroes = ['Hurricane', 12, 'Wolf', 42, 'Zephyr', 28]`

Displaying the data via *ngFor:

```
 <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
 {{hero}}
 </div>
```

would render:

Hurricane
12
Wolf
42
Zephyr
28

However, what I need to display is:

Hurricane - 12 
Wolf - 42
Zephyr - 28

Is there a way to do this declaratively inside the Angular 2 template file?

See [Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sNjAFKBVono0hYcGs8zT?p=preview)

Comment: I would recommend using an array of objects rather than an array of keys and values. An array is more for storing one type of data so you know what to expect as you loop through it.

Comment: And with that, we are to celebrate. This one's for you, TrumanCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transform the array you received using Array Extras into objects that better fit your view.

```
['Hurricane', 12, 'Wolf', 42, 'Zephyr', 28]
    .map(function(curr, index, arr) { 
        if(typeof curr === 'number') 
            return {name: arr[index-1], id: curr } 
        })
    .filter(function(val) { return val })
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2010/12/13/ecmascript-5-part-2-array-extras/

Answer (score 3):

you can change `heroes = [{name:'Hurricane', age:12}, {name:'Wolf', age:42}, {name:'Zephyr', age:28}]`

Display the data `<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
 {{hero.name}} - {{hero.age}}
 </div>`

Comment: The challenge is that the data comes from an external source so we have to use it as is.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function inside the component using cboston's code:

```
mapArray(args){
   var results = args.map(function (current, index, arr) {
        if(typeof current == 'number'){
            return {
                name: arr[index - 1],
                age: current
            }
        }
    }).filter(function(val) {
        return val;
    });

    return results;
}
```

Then, the Angular 2 client side markup looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of mapArray(heroes)">
  {{hero.name}} : {{hero.age}}
 </div>
```

Plunk available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YnIL5drfWzIL5gMc1Efd?p=info